# xamarin mono remote Debug via ssh

Tags: xamarin, mono

I am working on a C# Console application that runs on a Linux server with mono.
I want to debug the application from my Xamarin installed on my workstation.
Is there a way to debug a network/remote application with Xamarin ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, now there is

You can use the SSH Remote debugger add in with Xamarin studio or MonoDevelop.
[ssh remote debugger](https://github.com/logicethos/SSHDebugger)

The add in can be installed from the add in manager (via nugget).

It is very simple to use.  There is a video showing that it works.  I have been unable to get it to work (I can't get past password authentication).

However, it looks very promising. I hope more people start to use it so if there are bugs they can be worked out and I can figure out how to get past my problem.

Good Luck